# unable to print the Error Message while running a R script through try and catch

Tags: r, try-catch

I am running a r script in within try and catch. I am looking to Print the error message received as we see in console, in case of error. and also the script should stop running from that point.
below code I am trying to run...

```
a <- tryCatch({
  source("Script.R")
}, error = function(e) {
  print("error")
})
```

Instead of just error I would want the error message to be printed as a result in case of failure.

Comment: There is no way to move the `tryCatch` inside the `Script.R`

Comment: Probably print(e)?